# Testing every SMB command

Tags: samba, smb

I want to modify samba to add some security features.
After doing the modification, I want to verify that the responses of all the SMB requests are valid.
However, I don't know how to the SMB clients to trigger some of the commands, such as trans2.query_path_info.unix_info2.

Are there any ways to test all of SMB commands supported by samba?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick Google search seems to show that Samba comes with a pretty comprehensive test suite.

From http://ftp.samba.org/pub/samba/slides/samba4_testing_tutorial.pdf:

> The Samba4 testsuite consists of the following
>     - basic components:
>     - smbtorture ad-hoc tests
>     - smbtorture individual (RAW) tests
>     - levelscanners
>     - smbclient
>     - gentest
>     - locktest
>     - locktest2
>     - masktest
>
> "A levelscanner is a program that tries every
>   subcall and information level of a CIFS
>   transaction requestsuch as TRANS2"